# Read-only and non-realtime mode activated in the data viewer to improve browser performance || Now Database is Very slow working

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Suddenly I am facing this issue, They show message on Real Time Database that define in title. after that database performance slow down on both platforms on my mobile App and web. I want to get out of this mode to previous one.
Can I go back to that mode and how to go there, I already tried solution that discussed by community on this topic, but I can't go back back completely.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it happened because of too many nodes inside of my some nodes, I just deleted All the sub nodes now it's working fine.
it's like something,

```
--database
   -----user
   -------------jobs
   --------------------1
   ---------------------2
```

and so on,
if you avoid like this it will back to realtime